# how to retrieve Json as string from url?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-7

I have a URL which returns JSON. I am developing an app in windows phone where I want to get that json data by sending the url and then convert it into string and extract data from it. I have downloaded json.net to read the json data.
Do I have to deserialize the data.. Is that necessary?
Can't I just get the data in string format and then parse  it.

I am using the following code to read the json data which is in string format.

```
Array Movies = jObject["movies"].ToArray();
foreach (JToken Movie in Movies)
    MessageBox.Show(Movie["title"].ToString());
```

The json looks like this:

```
{"total":51,"movies":[{"id":"771242005","title":"Magic Mike","year":2012,"mpaa_rating":"R","runtime":110,"critics_consensus":"Magic Mike's sensitive direction, smart screenplay, and strong performances allow audiences to have their beefcake and eat it too.","release_dates":{"theater":"2012-06-29","dvd":"2012-10-23"},"ratings":{"critics_rating":"Certified Fresh","critics_score":79,"audience_rating":"Upright","audience_score":63},"synopsis":"Set in the world of male strippers, Magic Mike is directed by Steven Soderbergh and stars Channing Tatum in a story inspired by his real life. The film follows Mike (Tatum) as he takes a young dancer called The Kid (Pettyfer) under his wing and schools him in the fine arts of partying, picking up women, and making easy money. -- (C) Warner Bros.","posters":{"thumbnail":"http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166610_mob.jpg","profile":"http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166610_pro.jpg","detailed":"http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166610_det.jpg","original":"http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166610_ori.jpg"},"abridged_cast":[{"name":"Channing Tatum","id":"162661835","characters":["Magic Mike"]},{"name":"Alex Pettyfer","id":"326298019","characters":["Adam","The Kid"]},{"name":"Matt Bomer","id":"771077752","characters":["Ken"]},{"name":"Joe Manganiello","id":"770800475","characters":["Big Dick Richie"]},{"name":"Matthew McConaughey","id":"162652350","characters":["Dallas"]}],"alternate_ids":{"imdb":"1915581"},"links":{"self":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005.json","alternate":"http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/magic_mike/","cast":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005/cast.json","clips":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005/clips.json","reviews":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005/reviews.json","similar":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005/similar.json"}}],"links":{"self":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/upcoming.json?page_limit=1&country=us&page=1","next":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/upcoming.json?page_limit=1&country=us&page=2","alternate":"http://www.rottentomatoes.com/dvd/upcoming.json"},"link_template":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/upcoming.json?page_limit={results-per-page}&page={page-number}&country={country-code}"}
```

`

I want only movie name and title though.

Comment: Make your sample json small and clean, no one can read it

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "Is it necessary to deserialize", then the answer is no, it is not necessary.

That said, deserializing a JSON string into a strongly typed object is often preferred when working with data server side as it can reduce run time errors and make it easier to test your code.

Example using [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx):

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public Movie Convert(string jsonString)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(jsonString);
}
```

There are other options for deserializing JSON into an object.  If you have a DataContract that represents the JSON object you can use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).